# Could not import Xamarin.ObjcBinding.CSharp.targets

Tags: objective-c, binding, static-libraries, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I have unistall and installed Xamarin Studio on same Mac computer (because a have some problem with mono). Now all work properly except a project that bind a ObjectC library (previously that works fine). That is the error:

> MyBindingProject.csproj could not import "$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Xamarin\Xamarin.ObjcBinding.CSharp.targets"

There is no file Xamarin.ObjcBinding.CSharp.targets on that path. I have tried also to recreate a new iOS Binding Project but that doesn't solve it. How could i solve?

> === Xamarin Studio ===
>
> Version 4.0.10 (build 5)
>
> Runtime:  Mono 3.2.0 ((no/7c7fcc7)
>
> === Apple Developer Tools ===
>
> Xcode 5.0.2 (3335.32) Build 5A3005
>
> === Xamarin.Mac ===
>
> Xamarin.Mac: Not Installed
>
> === Xamarin.iOS ===
>
> Version: 7.0.4.209 (Business Edition) Branch:  Build date: 2013-11-11
>   16:04:00-0500
>
> === Xamarin.Android ===
>
> Version: 4.8.0 (Business Edition)
>
> === Operating System ===
>
> Mac OS X 10.8.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reinstalled just Xamarin.iOS and problem it's solved

Answer (score 0):

I had a half-baked copy paste install, and had this same error with Xamarin iOS 10.x (shortly to be replaced by Visual Studio for Mac). I went to the "Check for updates" and switched from the stable channel to Alpha to properly reload the Xamarin iOS.